# Do I need to buy FFXIV:ARR if I already own FFXIV?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

Square Enix seems to be treating them like separate games at times, but also calls them just fixing the old one. I can't find any conclusive evidence on this. What do I need to do to play?

Update:

I try logging into the website to download the client, and it says I need to sign in to the game first. I can't sign in to the game until I have the client installed, but my disks are for the old client. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Try logging in at https://secure.square-enix.com. Then navigate to **Services and Options**, **Select Service**, and finally **FINAL FANTASY XIV**. Alternately, just navigate to https://secure.square-enix.com/account/app/svc/mogstation and make sure you're logged in. That should tell you whether you have an account, and what kind of subscription it has, if any (should be standard with 7 days remaining today).

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann That comment works well as (part of an) answer. I'm going to give them a shot soon.

Comment: Go ahead and add it to mine if you find it satisfactory.

Comment: Well, I didn't need to use that link, I got your link below working. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Enjoy the game!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you played the original Fourteen, you already have an account, and all you need to play (even with your old character, if you like) is go to account management and subscribe.

Having Legacy status (obtained by being subscribed to the original Fourteen for three months) gives you a permanent discount on ARR subscription.

In either case, if you already had an account at ARR's release, you should have gotten two weeks of subscription for free. As of this writing, you should still have a week left: try logging into the game.

Comment: Of course, you'll probably have trouble logging into the game for other reasons right now...but in a few days you should (hopefully) have no trouble!

Comment: At the very least, "go away, all servers are full" and "go away, you're not subscribed" are different messages.

Comment: How do I get the game? I have a new computer since then. Do I install from the original disc?

Comment: That is surprisingly difficult. Here's the link: http://www.finalfantasyxiv.com/playersdownload/na/
Your original disc now contains an almost entirely different game and more likely than not won't work.